# How to handle appstream:// links in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, appstream

I have some AppStream links (for ex.: appstream://org.kde.k3b.desktop) that I want to open, I tried to find an app to open them but couldn't find any, so any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: What browser are you trying to use? In theory they are automatically handled in any default official *Ubuntu installation. Can you also edit the question and add the output of `apt-cache policy appstream`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you developing some sort of software center? Is [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/docs/sect-AppStream-Services-URIHandler.html) related?

Comment: @dadexix86 I'm using Firefox and here's the output of `apt-cache policy appstream` :  `appstream:
  Installed: 0.12.0-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.12.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.12.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.12.0-3 500
        500 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: @DKBose I'm trying to install some software and no it is not

Comment: Ok, so, let's take a step back. What do you want to do with these links exactly? Because maybe they don't do what you think they do.

Comment: @dadexix86 they are KDE apps that I'm trying to install

Comment: Ok, where are you finding these links? Can you provide the website you got them from? If your goal is to install them, you can always find them in the Software Center.

Comment: @dadexix86 [link](https://kde.org/applications/development/org.kde.kdevelop)

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's going on. When I use a appstream link it asks me to open it with xdg-open, but this one too does not work to open it. I have no idea how to help you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant to your situation, but for the sake of posterity:
At least for Ubuntu, download "Discover" [software center] from the "Ubuntu Software" app. From there, AppStream links should work fine.

Comment: I’ll give it a shot

Comment: It worked but I don’t know how to mark this question as solved

Comment: @user3090933 click on the gray check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @user3090933 If it is still unclear, check this out https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/281134